# Flex drop element when too big

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, layout, mobile

In Flex Mobile I have a few buttons in the action bar. On devices with very small screen (such as the HTC Wildfire) not all buttons can be shown. Is there a way to tell Flex to hide an element when it doens't fit? I know it is possible by using states and test the width of the screen but I hope there is another way..

Comment: Are you using a % based width layout for content in your actionbar? If you are and content is still being dropped you're going to have to do something with states. It might also be worthwhile to re-visit your design and see if it's possible to decrease the space used in the actionbar

Comment: I'm using fixed widths because the buttons all have icons. Re-visit is not neccessary because the Wildfire is afaik the only device which can't display all buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *really simple* Spark layout class that lays out the objects horizontally, dropping any items that won't fit.

```
package
{
    import mx.core.ILayoutElement;

    import spark.layouts.supportClasses.LayoutBase;

    public class DroppableHorizontalLayout extends LayoutBase
    {
        private static const PADDING:Number = 5;

        public function DroppableHorizontalLayout()
        {
            super();
        }

        override public function updateDisplayList(width:Number, height:Number):void
        {
//          super.updateDisplayList(width,height); // super method doesn't do anything
            var currentXCoordinate:Number = 0;
            var numKids:int = target.numChildren;
            for (var i:int=0; i < numKids; i++)
            {
                var currentItem:ILayoutElement = target.getElementAt(i);
                var itemWidth:Number = currentItem.getPreferredBoundsWidth();
                if (currentXCoordinate + itemWidth < width)
                {
                    currentItem.setLayoutBoundsSize(itemWidth, currentItem.getPreferredBoundsHeight());
                    currentItem.setLayoutBoundsPosition(currentXCoordinate, 0); // or whatever the Y coordinate should be
                    currentXCoordinate = currentXCoordinate + itemWidth + PADDING;
                }
                else
                {
                    break; // no reason to keep iterating, nothing else will fit...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Writing layouts that have all the functionality of a typical Flex layout class is not trivial. But you can certainly do simple things like the above, to iterate over the child objects, set their size/position, and in this case, not bother rendering things that won't fit.

Comment: For some reason when I put this in actionLayout all elements were just hidden. I had to tweak your code a bit. Now it also works for the action bar. Thank you

Comment: Great! You may want to edit the answer and add the tweaks you made for it to work when used w/the ActionBar (actionLayout property). I tested it w/a Group, and it worked, but didn't try anything more than that :)

Comment: I coded it quick and dirty but it works, I will add it to your answer

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the [ApplicationDPI](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html) value; and hide explicit things on higher resolutions.  Most tablets providea 160dpi; while most phones provide a 240dpi.  The iPhone 4 provides a 320dpi screen.  I'm not sure about the iPad Retina Display screen.

Comment: Purely using a dpi based layout will be tricky. The iPad 3 and upcoming 1080p Android tables have a resolution around 260dpi (264 for the iPad to be exact), so will be marked as 240dpi by flex.

Comment: @Al_Birdy Agreed; it really depends what you want to do and what you want to target and how "Future proof" the code needs to be.